# MSI file command line argument parsing

Tags: c++, wix

I have created a MSI file of my project using Wix, developed in Visual C++. Based on some research, I found that msiexec can be used to give custom parameter as:

```
msiexec setup.msi IP_ADDR="127.0.0.1" PORT="9999"
```

How should I parse those arguments and create a text file with the contents as:

```
{
"IP_ADDR":"127.0.0.1",
"PORT":"9999"
}
```

I have looked at the [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16767/How-to-Pass-Command-Line-Arguments-to-MSI-Installe) and it is making a C# installer. Can Wix be used for parsing the those parameters and creating the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to create your own code to do that. I'm pretty sure WiX has no built-in support for turning properties into text in a file. That guy is NOT making a C# installer. Despite the fact that the method is called "Install" it's just a custom action. WiX and Visual Studio provide a framework for managed code custom actions because they are not directly supported like C++ and VBScript are (as calls). If you're using WiX, and you're a C# fan there is this kind of thing:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/511653/using-wix-with-managed-custom-action

but there are C++ Dll calls or executeables too. Those values on the command line appear as case-sensitive prioperties in the install that you generally pass to custom action code by enclosing them in square brackets.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters.aspx